# Asp.net Identity OwinContext FacebookAuthentication for multiple domain site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

i have one site that has multiple domains. 
For example example.com, example.fr are linked to one asp.net mvc site. 
I need to configure asp.net identity FacebookAuthentication for multiple domain site.
Something like this

```
var facebookAuthenticationOptionsCom = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{

AppId = // appid for example.com
AppSecret = // appid for .com
AuthenticationType = "facebook",
SignInAsAuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
//Domain = ".com"
};

var facebookAuthenticationOptionsFr = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{

AppId = // appid for example.fr
AppSecret = // appid for example.fr
AuthenticationType = "facebook",
//Domain = ".fr"
};


app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptionsCom);
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptionsFr);
```

There is any solution ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want Single Sign On(SSO) for cross-domain ASP.NET applications?

Comment: No, each website has own authentication.